# undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_pure_virtual@@CXXABI_1.3'

Tags: compilation, makefile, ubuntu-14.04

I'm faced with the following error when I run make for the files from https://github.com/liuliu/ccv

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/liblinear.a(linear-static.o): 
undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_pure_virtual@@CXXABI_1.3'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: 
error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My makefile is as follows:

```
include ../lib/config.mk
# CC += -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer # -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
LDFLAGS := -L"../lib" -lccv $(LDFLAGS)
CFLAGS := -O3 -Wall -I"../lib" $(CFLAGS)

TARGETS = bbffmt msermatch siftmatch bbfcreate bbfdetect scdcreate scddetect 
swtcreate swtdetect dpmdetect tld icfcreate icfdetect icfoptimize cifar-10 
image-net cnnclassify aflw dpmcreate

all: libccv.a $(TARGETS)

clean:
${MAKE} clean -C ../lib ; rm -f *.o $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): %: %.o libccv.a
$(CC) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

libccv.a:
${MAKE} -C ../lib

%.o: %.c ../lib/ccv.h
$(CC) $< -o $@ -c $(CFLAGS)
```

And the config.mk is as follows:

```
CC := clang
AR := ar
NVCC := 
CUDA_OBJS := 
DEFINE_MACROS := -D HAVE_LIBPNG -D HAVE_LIBJPEG -D HAVE_FFTW3 -D HAVE_LIBLINEAR 
-D HAVE_TESSERACT -D HAVE_AVCODEC -D HAVE_AVFORMAT -D HAVE_SWSCALE -D
USE_DISPATCH -D HAVE_SSE2 -D HAVE_GSL
prefix := /usr/local
exec_prefix := ${prefix}
CFLAGS := -fblocks -msse2 $(DEFINE_MACROS) -I${prefix}/include
NVFLAGS := --use_fast_math -arch=sm_30 $(DEFINE_MACROS)
LDFLAGS := -L${exec_prefix}/lib -lm -lpng -ljpeg -lfftw3 -lfftw3f -lpthread -llinear 
-ltesseract -lavcodec -lavformat -lswscale -ldispatch -lBlocksRuntime -lgsl 
-lgslcblas
```

I've tried seeking help from the developer(was helpful with most queries), read through the make file tutorials and search similar problems but still don't understand what needs to be done.

Please help.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `CC := clang++` for C++? likely that is why the linker is not automatically linking the `libstdc++` library

Comment: I tried what you suggested. But there are errors similar to the following: '(.text+0x10c4): undefined reference to `dscal_'
../lib/liblinear.a(tron-static.o): In function `TRON::trcg(double, double*, double*, double*)':

Comment: That's a different error, and imho you should start a different question. It is likely either a missing library or an incorrect library link order: how exactly did you decide your `LDFLAGS`?

Comment: I didn't decide the LDFLAGS. It was decided by the developer. I'll check the issue with the library link order in mind. Thank you for your advices.

Comment: @steeldriver, life-saving answer for beginners.